# How to push to array single objects from a multi dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have this array:

```
0: {links: www.example.com, coordinates: 8.99, 5.00}
1: {links: www.exampleB.com, coordinates: 5.99, 2.00}
```

And on ajax success I need to push each single value to an array, I tried:

```
success: function(data) {
  coords = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    coords.push(data.coordinates[i]);
  };
...
```

But I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

On this line:

```
coords.push(data.coordinates[i]);
```

Comment: `I have this array:` What exactly are you logging there?

Comment: @CertainPerformance what do you mean? I push values to a multidimensional array, and that is the structure I get. I then would like to push each single value to a specific new array

Comment: it looks like `data` is an array so you need to index into it to get at one set of coordinates: `data[i].coordinates[j]`

Comment: I mean, what did you `console.log` to get that output? Is that the `data`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes indeed

Comment: Does an array have a coordinates property? _Hint - no._ An **entry** may have a coordinates property, but not the array itself...

Comment: @MarkMeyer yes indeed, I was doing it the wrong way. Adding the index to coordinates and not data. Tired. Thanks

Comment: @MarkMeyer actually I now do:               `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                coords.push(data[i].coordinates);
                links.push(data[i].links);
              };` but that is adding twice a value as I get `0: ["40.7272074, 8.575266499999998"]
1: (2) ["40.7272074, 8.575266499999998", "40.7197406, 8.563512299999957"]` I might have to do a array unique unless there is another way

Comment: had to do `coords.push(data[i].coordinates[i]);  links.push(data[i].links[i]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access the correct item in `data`:

```
coords.push(data[i].coordinates);
```

Comment: oh thanks a lot, I was doing it the wrong way. Adding the index to coordinates and not data. Will accept it as soon as it let me to.

Comment: ctually I now do: for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { coords.push(data[i].coordinates); links.push(data[i].links); }; but that is adding twice a value as I get 0: ["40.7272074, 8.575266499999998"] 1: (2) ["40.7272074, 8.575266499999998", "40.7197406, 8.563512299999957"] I might have to do a array unique unless there is another way

Comment: had to do `coords.push(data[i].coordinates[i]);  links.push(data[i].links[i]);`